# Installing CUDA 7.5 on CentOS 7 - Unable to locate the kernel source

Tags: linux, cuda, centos7

First of all, all of this is done as root. I've been trying to install the CUDA 7.5 drivers on a CentOS 7 SATA DOM. The issue I'm running into is the following:

```
Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please make sure that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly.
If you know that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly, you may pass the location of the kernel source with the '--kernel-source-path' flag.
```

I have tried to point to the kernel source path (I may be pointing to the wrong path; I'm a new Linux user) with the following command:

```
$ ./cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --kernel-source-path=/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
```

Same issue as before. I've read online that other people with this issue is due to kernel version mismatch. That, however is not the case:

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
$ rpm -q kernel-devel kernel-headers
kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64

$ ls /usr/src/kernels
3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
$ ls /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64/
arch  block  crypto  drivers  firmware  fs  include  init  ipc  Kconfig  kernel  lib  Makefile  mm  Module.symvers  net  samples  scripts  security  sound  System.map  tools  usr  virt  vmlinux.id
```

I've also tried to install different versions of gcc and still no dice.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figure it out. It turns out I needed to install DKMS from the EPEL repository. Here are the commands I used:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
yum install --enablerepo=epel dkms
```

Comment: It worked for me for CUDA8.0 on RHEL7.4. Thanks a lot !!